# Touchstart on the edge of target element causes mousedown

Tags: javascript, html, touch, dom-events

I noticed a very strange behavior, perhaps a bug. I have a vertical menu with anchors and separators. Anchors have custom event handlers for `mousedown`, `touchstart`, `pointerdown`. The problem is, when I tap and the finger covers both an anchor and a separator, (separator is more covered), then `mousedown` event is executed instead of `touchstart`. I managed to reproduce it in a simple sample.

I tested it on Android Chrome and on desktop with Chrome dev tools touch emulation. Just touch the area between anchor and separator and you will see that the browser registered `mousedown` event instead of `touchstart` event. Can somebody tell me what's wrong? Is it a bug or did I do something wrong?

This only happens with anchors, if there were paragraphs instead of anchors, it wouldn't happen.

Here is the sample:
http://jsbin.com/huhariluva/edit?js,console,output

Answer (score 0):

Edge does not support touch events. So touchstart does nothing and preventDefault is never called so mousedown is executed. You can use pointer events instead and use PEP to polyfill for chrome and other browsers.

Pointer Events: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/PointerEvent

PEP: https://github.com/jquery/PEP

Comment: I know about pointerevents. The issue happens on Chrome. I meant the edge as a boundary of anchor element, not Edge, the browser. Sorry for confuson.

Comment: I think chrome is firing mousedown to maintain compatibility of old sites with touch devices. touchstart is only firing if to touch the exact target and mousedown is fired even if you touch a little outside. Try touching a little below second green div. It will fire mousedown.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to overcome the problem. The solution is to add touchstart event listener to the other element that is clicked and causes the bug and call event.preventDefault() from there.

I also submitted the bug on chromium bug tracker.